# XCUITEST is not running while running from from terminal using xcodebuildcommand

Tags: xcodebuild, xcuitest

I have more than 50 test cases in my UI-TEST scheme and I am running it via the below command

xcodebuild test -workspace tribo.xcworkspace -scheme triboUITests -sdk iphonesimulator -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone X,OS=12.4'

what happens is the RAM of my Mac machine shoots up and the system hangs up , I have attached the activity monitor report too[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLIs7.jpg)

can anyone help me in running all XCUITEST cases present in scheme from terminal

Answer (score 0):

The console command itself seems legit.

The RAM problem also could be caused by inaccurate resource management in test code.

Consider inspecting your code for possible memory leakings and other bugs.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a specific test or tests as part of the xcodebuild invocation.

From the `xcodebuild help` command line:

```
-only-testing:TEST-IDENTIFIER constrains testing by specifying tests to include, and excluding other tests

-skip-testing                 constrains testing by specifying tests to exclude, but including other tests

-skip-testing:TEST-IDENTIFIER constrains testing by specifying tests to exclude, but including other tests
```

Using these commands may help you understand which tests are causing the issue.
You could also use the Xcode Memory Graph Debugger (see this link:
https://medium.com/zendesk-engineering/ios-identifying-memory-leaks-using-the-xcode-memory-graph-debugger-e84f097b9d15

Finally, you if you are trying to run all your tests in parallel, you may have too many simulators running on the machine.